# What is the difference between DirectoryStream and DirectoryStream.filter in java 7?

Tags: java, java-7

As the name says filtering is the only difference,or is there anything else?

Comment: They are not comparable as they don't even provide the same methods: DirectoryStream => iterator() vs. DirectoryStream.Filter => accept().

Answer (score 0):

**DirectoryStream** -->This static interface can be useful when you want to work with the content of a directory (e.g. the files it contains).

**DirectoryStream.Filter** -->This interface to list only files that are larger than given amount of kilobytes and also used to determine if the path object should be accepted.